# Terminology: abstraction vs models

Tags: terminology, abstraction, model

I'm building a model of the SQL query language.

It doesn't attempt to abstract SQL at all - instead, it tries to model it directly, so it has model objects named Query, Table, Column, Variable, Expression, Join, etc.

Contrast this with an object/relational mapper, which tries to abstract away SQL and the DBMS in favor of some new/different and (usually) higher-level abstractions.

My question is regarding the terminology to describe what I'm writing: generally, is a model always an abstraction? Is an abstraction always a model? Are they synonymous, more or less?

Specifically, is a model of SQL also an abstraction, or is it correct to describe it as just a model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is abstraction?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/16070/what-is-abstraction)

Comment: @gnat I read the accepted response to that question, and it resounds with my understanding of abstraction. But it doesn't resolve my question. In a nutshell, what is the difference between a model and an abstraction? Is one a superset of the other?

Answer (score 2):

This is highly philosophical, but:

A model is definitely an abstraction if it is trying to represent real-world entities, in which case, of course you cannot have cars, trees, houses etc. living inside the computer, so obviously, you are *abstracting*.

But if the model is not trying to represent a real-world entity, and instead it is a one-to-one mapping to *already abstract entities*, then I think it can safely be called a model, without the need to add the "abstraction" part.

However, the reasons to go one way or the other are trifling.

Comment: Does a model have to model a real-world entity? In this case, my domain is SQL, so the entities I'm modeling are Query, Condition, Join, etc. - even if those are already abstract entities (translating to an execution plan against physical data on a disk at a lower level) in terms of the domain I'm modeling, those are my entities, is that correct?

Comment: @mindplay.dk yes, of course, that's exactly what I am talking about, you may be modelling *already abstract* entities! so, you have a *model*, not an *abstract model*.